# Host a Httpie Server

Tags: node.js, httpie

I have a webapp with API documentation where the examples have the users using httpie to make requests. It would be extremely useful if the user could follow along on the same screen on a terminal, typing in the commands, making requests and the results are all shown on the same page.

It sounds like I would have to host some kind of httpie server. Would that be the only way to go? Would there be security concerns? How would this be done?

Comment: A quick google learns: HTTPie is a debugging tool for rest-api's (see postman chrome extension for another tool). The server is just a rest-api httpie is used to test it.

Comment: You wouldn't need to host any servers other than your documentation server and API server. Once those exist you could easily add a text box to the documentation pages and use javascript to simulate the requests. You don't even need HTTPie at that point the built-in fetch library would suffice.